# Write string format with boost asio write

Tags: c++, serial-port, boost-asio

I need help formatting my write string with boost asio.  I create a connection with `ttyS0` fine with `serial_port` and can read from my serial device fine.  I can enable my serial device using the command line like so `echo -en '\x35\x0d' > ttyS0`, now I would like to do this with my code.  What would the data string look like for this?  My write function is like so:

```
void serial_comm::write_data(std::string data)
{
    try
    {
        if (serial_port.get() == NULL || !serial_port->is_open())
        {
            WARNING << "serial port is not open";
            throw -2;
        }
        boost::asio::write(
            *serial_port,
            boost::asio::buffer(data.c_str(), data.size()), 
            boost::asio::transfer_at_least(data.size()),
            error
        );
        if (error) 
        {
            ERROR << "error.message() >> " << error.message().c_str();
            throw -3;
        }       
        flush_serial_port(WRITE);
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        ERROR << "e.what() = " << e.what();
        throw -1;
    }

    return;
}
```

I have tried making data equal to "0x35 0x0d" and "350d".  Does the hex need to be converted to binary instead?  Thank you.

Comment: Did you try sending the string `"\x35\x0D"`? (That's a two-character-long string, where the first character is 35 in hex and the second character is 0D in hex, using the `\x` escape sequences to insert characters based on their hex values)

Comment: @immibis no, I haven't; I didn't know you could do that; I'll try it at work my next chance

Comment: @immibis yes, that worked, thank you.  How do I convert (char) 5 & (char) CR to binary for the asio write?

Comment: What does "convert them to binary" mean?

Comment: @immibis I'm trying to write a function that does the same thing `\x35\x0D` does, but dynamically.  I know `\x` represents an ASCII character in hexadecimal notation, but I thought it's binary representation is why this works instead of 350D

Comment: Well, you can't write the four characters that look in ASCII like 3, 5, 0, D, (that is, the ones with hex codes 33, 35, 30, 44) because that's not what the device is expecting. You write the characters with hex codes 35, 0D. Note that the character itself doesn't have any "hex-ness" about it; hex is just *the way I'm writing the characters down*.

Comment: @immibis OK; is there any way to encapsulate the escape sequence in a function?

Comment: That's not a question that makes sense. It's like asking if there is any way to ski your dishwasher in a fire hydrant.

Comment: @immibis OK; I have hard coded all of my write commands and control characters like `\x35` and `\x0d`, then build my write string from that.  You can post that as an answer and I'll accept it.